# How to check if help button is pressed on wizard page programatically in java

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, wizard

I have created a Wizard with four Wizard pages.On the second page , I want to do some action only when the help button is pressed, is there a way where i can check programatically if the help (F1) button is pressed?While Creating the wizard page i am trying to extend "Wizard" which inturn extends "DialogPage".

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: send your code so that we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `WizardPage` you can override the `performHelp` method to do something when the Help button is pressed:

```
@Override
public void performHelp() {
   ... your code ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know this method Greg.But my requirement is , There is a radio button on click of radio button ,inside the event listener i have to check if the help button is pressed , if it is already pressed then have to perform some actions.

Comment: So set a flag to remember that performHelp has been called.